# PDO returning empty for multiple condition

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo, php-7

> Table Items:

[image]

> Source

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `name` LIKE '%cell%' AND `is_active`=1";
// the query is generated dynamically so i do have a dynamic params too
$params = [
    'name'      => '%cell%',
    'is_active' => 1,
];

$prepared = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($params as $key => $val)
{
    if(is_int($val))
    {
        $prepared->bindParam(':'.$key, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    else
    {
        $prepared->bindParam(':'.$key, $val);
    }
}
```

upon execution it returns empty result ..

**Not Working:**

multiple parameters .. (except i manually bind the parameters)

```
$prepared->bindParam(':name', $params['name']);
$prepared->bindParam(':is_active', $params['is_active']);
```

**Working:**

single parameter .. (it returns exactly what i needed)

Now my question, what could be the reason why it returns empty when looping the `bindParam()` ?

Comment: Sorry I might be missing something, but where are the placeholders for your bound params (e.g. :is_active) - I'd expect to see "SELECT * FROM `tbl_items` WHERE `name` LIKE '%:name%' AND `is_active`= :active", but perhaps this is a different style I'm not used to?  Have you tried printing out the connection error/php errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindParam` takes its value *by reference*. Meaning, at the time you do `execute()`, it takes the then current value of whatever is assigned to `$val`. Which obviously is probably not what you expect at the end of the loop.

Use `bindValue` instead, which binds the value immediately, instead of a variable reference.

Comment: hi I found the answer .. in my loop instead of using `$prepared->bindParam(':'.$key, $val);` I used `$prepared->bindParam(':'.$key, $params[$key]);` instead .. I don't get it why .. but it worked anyway ..

Comment: ahhh .. i see .. now i get it .. the time of execution the $val is no longer available .. thanks dude ..